# Cordova command line interface

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, angularjs-directive

when i install the cordova in my system i got error.how can i rectify this problem any one help me

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: 
wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: 
{
"node":"4.4.3","npm":"2.15.1"})
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: 
This package has been discontinued in fav
or of lodash@^4.0.0.
C:\Users\oscorp\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova ->
 C:\Users\oscorp\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@6.2.0 C:\Users\oscorp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, repeating@1.1.3, str
ing-length@1.0.1, chalk@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
├── insight@0.8.2 (object-assign@4.1.0, async@1.5.2, tough-cookie@2.2.2, node-uu
id@1.4.7, lodash.debounce@3.1.1, chalk@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, os-name@1.0.3,
request@2.72.0, inquirer@0.10.1)
├── cordova-common@1.3.0 (cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.15, unorm@1.4.1, underscor
e@1.8.3, q@1.4.1, ansi@0.3.1, semver@5.1.0, osenv@0.1.3, bplist-parser@0.1.1, sh
elljs@0.5.3, glob@5.0.15, minimatch@3.0.0, elementtree@0.1.6, plist@1.2.0)
└── cordova-lib@6.2.0 (cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.15, valid-identifier@0.0.1, o
pener@1.4.1, unorm@1.3.3, properties-parser@0.2.3, semver@4.3.6, nopt@3.0.6, dep
-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, glob@5.0.15, elementtree@0.1.6, cordova-serve@1.0.0
, request@2.47.0, init-package-json@1.9.4, aliasify@1.9.0, cordova-app-hello-wor
ld@3.10.0, cordova-fetch@1.0.0, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.2.0, cordova-js@4.1.4, xcode@
0.8.7, npm@2.15.6)
```

im using cordova command line interface using this process and first am install node js and after then am try to install cordova

Comment: This isn't an error, just warnings about old packages. Try to type `cordova -v`

Answer (score 0):

First install new version of **`Node.js`** after that install cordova using  this command

**`npm install -g cordova`**

click here to download  node.js [click here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

[read more here](http://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: thank you yar .just now only i tryed and i got it. thank you so much

Comment: Hi,am tryed android material  i  can not develop anything can u help me any thingelse